# d3.js, add additional data to pre-existing elements

Tags: javascript, d3.js

In D3.js, how does one add additional data to a selector that's already got a data binding?

For example:

```
var nums = [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4];
var nums2 = [5, 6, 7];
var s1 = d3.select("body").selectAll("p").data(nums).enter().append("p").html(function(d) { return d; });
var s2 = d3.select("body").selectAll("p").data(nums2).enter().append("p").html(function(d) { return d; });
console.log("s1", s1);
console.log("s2", s2);
```

Creates paragraphs 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, but does not create paragraphs 5, 6 and 7. Additionally, by peeking into groups s1 and s2, I notice that group s2 has the elements that I requested to be created, but the elements weren't added to the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

For the above mentioned example, try this -

```
var nums = [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4];
var nums2 = [5, 6, 7];
var s1 = d3.select("body").selectAll("p").data(nums , function(d){return d;}).enter().append("p").html(function(d) { return d; });
var s2 = d3.select("body").selectAll("p").data(nums2, function(d){return d;}).enter().append("p").html(function(d) { return d; });
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Although this answer is correct, it is not even near being a good answer. There is no hint on why this solves the problem nor any further information. This touches the most essential concepts of D3, yet the answer does not mention data joins, key functions or enter selections. There are so many great tutorials or the API docs one could link to. Please edit your answer to include at least some more information.